# youtube-dl format option for best audio and video does not working in live streams

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I use youtube-dl to stream videos from youtube. I use this format to stream/download youtube non-live videos of quality less than 720p which works fine.

```
youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=?720]+bestaudio'  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubk3dvOdYzg
```

But for live youtube videos

```
youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=?720]+bestaudio' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ij2rYpNxXgM
```

its showing this error

> ERROR: requested format not available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format says to take the best video-only stream below 720p and mux it together with the best audio stream. However, in this case, the live stream in question does not seem to have individual streams, just one stream with picture *and* audio.

To support these kinds of videos, add that format (`best[height<=?720]'` in your case) to your format specification:

```
youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[height<=?720]+bestaudio/best[height<=?720]' Ij2rYpNxXgM
```

If you always want videos in 720p or less, you can also write `-f 'bestvideo[height<=?720]+bestaudio/best[height<=?720]'` into a [configuration file](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#configuration) so you don't have to type it out all the time.

Comment: Is it really necessary to specify the maximum height for the audio part, too?